Instagram instagram_manage_insights permission for Extract and Load Data tool
We have a Data tool which extracts data for client's instagram account and loads it in their data destinations like BigQuery or Snowflake, etc.
We recently applied for instagram_manage_insights permission which got rejected because the facebook review team wants the insights data to be displayed in our application as a table or any visualization which is not possible right now.
Is there any other ways in which we can get the instagram_manage_insights permission without showing insights data inside our application?
We did show the insights data as a table in BigQuery in our screencast to Facebook team, which we hoped would be sufficient for the app review. Also, explained that we do not store any client data on our systems.
